# Way to choose a "default" navbar of a Bootstrap Material theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I'm using the [Bootstrap Material Design Template](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) for a website. It has [three different colored navbars](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) of which I want to use the last one. But I'm unsure how to use that last one. Do I need to manually change the color of the navbar, or can I change one thing somewhere so that the color of all the buttons and radio buttons also changes?

I found a piece on the github page which points out how to [change the primary color to a cusom one](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design#use-custom-color-as-primary). But I don't want that, I simply want to use the blue color which you see in the [third navbar option here](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html).

Any ideas how I can do that? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to use **different classes** for change in colors, by default a Bootstrap theme have `navbar-default` and `navbar-inverse`
But in the very theme you're using have a class called `navbar-material-light-blue-300` which needs to be added in following manner.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-material-light-blue-300">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-material-light-blue-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-material-light-blue-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="index.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search">
              </form>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="index.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

`.navbar-inverse` is the class that affecting its color.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  ....
</div>
```

Other two above than the third have `.navbar-default` and `.navbar-warning` classes respectively.

Use below code:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">One more separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <input class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```